# Exclude a Substring using Regex in Java

Tags: negation

I want to take a string like `src=' blah src='' blah` and ignore the first `src='`

Expected results should be: `blah src='' blah`

I've tried: `blah(?!:(src\\s*?=\\s*?))`

I've seen other posts on here mentioning ^(...).*$ but I really don't understand how to apply that or really how to work with negation.  The java tutorial mentions [^abc], but can that be used for a regular expression too not just characters?  e.g. [^src\\s=]

Comment: Why does this not work: ^(?!.*(src=)|(src\\s=)).*$

Answer (score 0):

Simple "src'(.*)" should do the work unless you have more complicated cases:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "src='(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.match( "src=' blah src='' blah");

if ( matcher.find( )) {
   String result = matcher.group(1); // Here is the extracted string just like you wanted.
}
```

Comment: I think I get what you're saying here, but doesn't that also match the strings I don't want?  I'm trying to apply a concept to a small example so I can understand it for when I tackle the bigger mess I need to face.